# How do I custom field suite groups into the database automatically

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

The title does not do its justice, I apologies for that.
I am currently working on a Wordpress website built using Twig, I am also using the Custom Field Suite plugin.

I want to be able to write a function that inserts the Custom Field Suite groups into the database automatically, using a function that checks if it exists, if it does not exist then it should insert it in. This should preferably be a function that checks if a Custom Field is in the database and if it isn't then it needs to insert it.

Any ideas?

P.S. This is my first question so I am sorry if it is not descriptive enough :)

Comment: Sorry about the title it should read "How do I automatically insert a custom field into the my database automatically"

Comment: Well, first you'd have to understand how the plugin works. Does it use WP tables or does it have it's own custom tables. The database scheme would be required. I would advise contacting the author. They may have code to help out with these types of requests.

Comment: It uses the following tables that it inserts manually

Comment: wp_cfs_values and wp_cfs_sessions
the cfs_values table seems to join to the multiple tables as it requires a filter on where these fields should appear when editing a section of the website (a post, a page..etc) this is my confusion though. There must be a way to insert these into the database, I think I will get in contact with the author of this plugin.

Comment: There's an edit button

Comment: Strawberry, could you elaborate? What edit button are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

If you are after synchronizing data between 2 seperate environments - then without knowing exactly how CFS works it will be difficult to build something to do this.

I would suggest pulling a backup of the live production db to local where you can add the fields once and then re-deploy your updated db to the live production server.

There is probably a tool out there which you can use to help with this process =]